# Supertype question from a mega noob

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, ssms, sql-server-2008-r2

I've tried a couple database creation tools (MS SQL Server, MySQL Workbench, etc.) and I cannot figure out how to create a super-type relation (complete, disjoint). Below is an example of how it looks in crow's foot notation. Even a link to a tutorial would help a lot, as the subject states, I'm a total noob at SQL / Databases.

[image]

Comment: I think you're going to have to give a bit more detail on what you're trying to do.  It seems to me that you'd just create your three entities, then declare whichever fields are your foreign keys from D and E to B.

Comment: Maybe that's what I want to do... let me give the correct [diagram](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/XIaF1QBQTSkXipeCKPX8Eg?feat=directlink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi a good start might actually be with an MS Access Database.  If you are looking for a good graphical interpretation I think what you might want would be what they call relationships.

I would start with Access, and then move in to SQL server.  While they differ in a lot of ways it could be a good stepping stone for you.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-HA010072597.aspx

You can also import/export from SQL to Access, but I wouldn't make that a habit due to the differences between the systems.

Otherwise there is a few tutorials over at the MySql Workbench [website](http://wb.mysql.com/?page_id=10), the one by Djoni Darmawikarta was pretty good for beginners.